# How to stop login sharing for our employees?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

We need to stop employee sharing login password among them. They use login for POS terminal (Windows App C# + SQL Server 2008, not web interface).

We have list of names and passwords for authorized employees on the SQL Server database. But I don't know how to detect other employee already logged in with same login details when someone tries to log in.

Comment: you mean Admin previleges? to detect user logged in ?

Comment: on signing in, just check if the login is already logged and if so, disallow login!

Comment: Don't try to solve it with technology. It's a people issue. If you make it a warning/firing offence, they may start to take it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

theoretically this should work (haven't tried)

**Create a Logon Trigger on the server**

- check logged in user name using USER_NAME() or SUSER_SNAME()
- check current Process ID usig SPID()
- query the sys.dm_db_exec_session and check if there are other session
  using the same User ID
- if yes, kill current Process ID

Comment: I'd usually advise, if you're going to do any form of session killing, to kill the old connection rather than the new one. This helps to reduce issues where, for whatever reason, a zombie session has been left behind that the user cannot (easily) identify and kill. If you kill any new connection attempts, they have to seek external help to regain access to the system. Whereas if you kill the old connection, users can clean up zombies without help.

Comment: but that would mean that every new login will kill the old "original" one.

Comment: yes, that's correct. If the objective is that each user should have only one session, why is the old one necessarily better than the new one? And if the objective is to "educate" users into not sharing their credentials, having them lose access when the credentials are re-used can be a valuable learning experience.

Comment: I assume that the first one is the "original" authorized one, and subsequent logins are the "shared" unauthrized ones.
Just imagine a legitimate user operating on the application and have its connection killed by another user whom he has shared its credential...anyway...up to the OP to decide to kill old or new ones...